# RESTClient error message

Tags: java, rest, utf-8

I'm getting this error form **RESTClient** application when I'm returning a String with Turkish characters inside, but Turkish characters could be able to be encoded using UTF-8:

**"Response body conversion to string using UTF-8 encoding failed. Response body not set!"**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Logging the message on the server side maybe helps you.

Comment: there's no error on the server-side, i just return string to the client and there's nothing to do with server-side after that... I think the problem is with RestClient app

Comment: I mean the string response body and not message error... Then with this string see what your client are trying to do. Also paste some code to be more easy to help.